# FB App not displaying on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, facebook, mobile

I setup a simple fan-gate app for my page and it displays perfectly on web browsers and my iPad browser, however on my android mobile browser it gives an error "this page can not be displayed"

Why is this?

Here is the link:
https://www.facebook.com/PeploesWineBistro/app_462665167164087

Answer (score 0):

check out Facebook application configuration for mobile

Comment: I have a secure link listed for my apps mobile site url: https://secure3066.hostgator.com:443/~w8expert/gocreatesocialmedia.com/fb/peploes/